# as being arbitrary

Tags: understanding

> Many people object to mandatory retirement at age 65 **as being
>   arbitrary**, arguing that people over 65 make useful contributions.
>   However, if those who reach 65 are permitted to continue working
>   indefinitely, we will face unacceptable outcomes.

I cannot understand the first sentence, especially the bold part. First, I thought "as being arbitrary" means "freeing mandatory retirement requirement" (which means that people could choose whether they will retire or not).

However, the following part ("arguing that people over 65 make useful contributions") make me confused, because when I combine it with the prior part of the sentence, the whole sentence means "people disagree with making retirement requirement into free choice, because people over 65 make contribution" which sounds like a paradox. So I am guessing the interpretation that I made for "as being arbitrary" is wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: @user3169 - No, the retirement is mandatory; the choice of age 65 is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

> Many people object to [something] **as (being) arbitrary**.

This section suggests that the "something" -- in this case "mandatory retirement at age 65" -- is thought of as "arbitrary".  In this context *arbitrary* means that there are no good reasons why 65 was chosen as the retirement age -- that, for example, 66 would be as good a number, or 67, or 70, or 75.

The argument is that many over 65 are perfectly capable, and are able to continue producing as well as younger workers.  'Useful contributions" is an inherently ambiguous statement, but the intended meaning is clear.

As written the sentence is slightly *wordy*, and unnecessarily convoluted, but not particularly difficult English.  It could have been written more directly as:

> Many argue that the choice of 65 as the mandatory age of retirement is arbitrary, since workers over 65 make useful contributions.